# Failed to run Taurus and ChromeDriver (non-headless) on EC2 linux machine

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So i'm trying to run a simple test with Taurus and selenium with chrome driver.

```
ubuntuXXXXXX$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72)


ubuntuXXXXXX$ google-chrome --version && which google-chrome
Google Chrome 73.0.3683.103
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

error logs:

```
INFO: Create JUnit 4 request with following arguments: [aws.BookAFlightNew]
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 28517
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1555756176.632][INFO]: [44084fb1ebc5abbc49f588f6d30790a8] COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "alwaysMatch": {
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [  ],
            "extensions": [  ]
         }
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [  ],
            "extensions": [  ]
         }
      },
      "firstMatch": [ {
         "browserName": "chrome"
      } ],
      "requiredCapabilities": {

      }
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [  ],
         "extensions": [  ]
      }
   },
   "requiredCapabilities": {

   }
}
[1555756176.632][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_setting_values": {
         "geolocation": 1
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[1555756176.632][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[1555756176.632][INFO]: Launching chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.gVwWj6/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.S44UB0 data:,
[1555756176.734][INFO]: [44084fb1ebc5abbc49f588f6d30790a8] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
[1555756176.734][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[1555756176.734][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

when adding to the config file headless chrome view, test is passed.

What do i miss?